# Compare two files and print matching data

Tags: linux

This is my first time posting in here so please forgive me if this isn't formatted properly. I am trying to post-process replica exchange data. I have File 1 which looks like this:

```
Time  Rep  
1000  1  
2000  2  
3000  3  
4000  2
```

And there are corresponding log files for each Rep titled:

```
file.1.log  
file.2.log  
file.3.log
```

Let's say each log file has 2 columns of data:
file1.log

```
1000  a          
2000  b          
3000  c           
4000  d
```

file2.log

```
1000  e          
2000  f         
3000  g           
4000  h
```

file3.log

```
1000  i          
2000  j          
3000  k           
4000  l
```

Now, for each line of File 1, I need to go to the corresponding log file and print the entire line with the matching time. So the result should appear as:

```
 Time  Rep     File     Data from File  
1000     1  file.1.log  1000 a   
2000  2     file.2.log  2000 f  
3000  3     file.3.log  3000 k   
4000  2     file.2.log  4000 h
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. But your are in a wrong place. Stackoverflow is _NOT_ a freelancing site.  Do some work by yourself and post it , you will get help

Comment: Got it, I just didn't know how to start. Next time I will :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score -1):

Thank you alex, I was over complicating my problem. I first just created a new file for every Rep column:

```
awk '{print $col}' file1 >> file2
```

Then pasted each one with the corresponding data file:

```
paste file2 file3 >> file4
```

From there I was able to rearrange and loop through all the values I needed:

```
awk "$1 == 0 {print $0}' file4 >> final.out
```

Answer (score -2):

is it something like that you want :

while read i; do grep "$i" file1; done < file2

they are more answers there :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156075/compare-two-files-and-print-matches